# Taking the inverse Laplace under boundary conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to solve the problem as described [here in this article](http://www.academia.edu/7350650/Finite_Element_Analysis_of_One_Dimensional_Bio-Heat_Transfer_in_Human_Tissue)
[image]

I am trying to solve it using **Laplace Transformation**.

This is what I did:
Taking Laplace transformation of the equation I get
$$K[s^2\hat T_0(s)-sT_0(0)-T'_0(0)]+ {MT_a\over s}-M\hat T_0(s)+{Q_m \over s}=0$$ where $M$ is the constant $\omega_b\rho_b\mathcal C_b$.

Using the boundary condition since $-K{dT_0(x)\over dx}=h_0[T_f-T_0(x)]$ and we have to convert the boundary condition from $x$ domain to Laplace domain and since at $x=0$, $h_0[T_f-T_0(0)]$ is a constant and  $L(a)=a/s$ where $a$ is a constant,
I get,
$$(Ks^2-M) \hat T_0(s)=KsT_0(0)-{h_0[T_f-T_0(0)] \over s}-{(Q_M+MT_a)\over s}.$$

Then taking the inverse Laplace I get,
$$T_0(x)=T_0(0)\cosh\left(\sqrt {M\over K}x\right)-h_0[T_f-T_0(0)]\left[{-x\over M}+{1\over M}\cosh\left(\sqrt {M\over K}x\right)\right]-(Q_m+MT_a)\left[{-x\over M}+{1\over M}\cosh\left(\sqrt {M\over K}x\right)\right].$$

Is this correct. I am not sure if I did right when adjusting the boundary condition from $x$ domain to Laplace domain.

Also I didn't need to use the condition $T_0(x)=T_c$ where $x=L$.
I can't use this to find $T_0(0)$,  since $T_0(x)=T_c $ is at $x=L$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Laplace transform is useless and ill-advised here, it creates a lot of confusion.

Basically the first line is a second order differential equation with constant coefficients: 
$$K\frac{\mathrm d^2T_0}{\mathrm dx^2}-MT_0=-MT_a-Q_m.\tag{1}$$ 
The solutions of the homogeneous equation ($ K\frac{\mathrm d^2T_0}{\mathrm dx^2}-MT_0=0$) are of the form $x\mapsto \exp[\alpha x]$ and $x\mapsto\exp[-\alpha x]$, where $\alpha$  is
here simply given by $$\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{M}{K}}.$$
To solve the full equation (1), it remains to find **one single solution** called special solution.
In that case it is particularly simple because the second member is a constant: a constant solution $T_0(x)=\text{constant}$ is solution when the constant is chosen to be $T_a+Q_m/M$.

So **all solutions** of (1) are of the form
$$ T(x)=T_a+\frac{Q_m}M+A\exp[\alpha x]+B\exp[-\alpha x],$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Applying the boundary conditions, you get the system for $A$ and $B$:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}T_a+\frac{Q_m}M+A\exp[\alpha L]+B\exp[-\alpha L]&=&T_c\\-K\alpha(A-B)&=&h_0\left[T_f-T_a-\frac{Q_m}M-A-B\right]\end{array}\right.$$
when you have found $A$ and $B$, you find $T_0(0)=T_a+\frac{Q_m}M+A+B$.

Comment: So what is done here is first solve the homogeneous equation $k{d^T_0(x)\over dx^2}-MT_0(x)=0$ and for its solution add the constant $MT_a+Q_m$ right?  But I don't understand how $-K\alpha(A-B)=h_o[T_f-MT_a-Q_m-A-B]$ is obtained? Can you please explain that part.Also I think $\alpha$ should be $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{M}{K}}.$

Comment: also if this could be solved simply like this then in this article  http://www.academia.edu/7350650/Finite_Element_Analysis_of_One_Dimensional_Bio-Heat_Transfer_in_Human_Tissue why have they gone into so much trouble to use **finite element method**

Comment: You are right concerning $\alpha$, I edited my answer. To obtain the boundary conditions, one simply replaces the expression for $T_0(x)$ into the last two equations. Note that $\mathrm dT_0/\mathrm dx=A\alpha\exp[\alpha x]-B\alpha\exp[-\alpha x]$ such that $\mathrm dT_0(x)/\mathrm dx|_{x=0}=\alpha(A-B)$.

Comment: In the paper, they give the analytical result for the steady state, this is equation (7). A second reason is probably that the paper is of very low quality.

Comment: Thanks got it. But can you please tell me in my post when I am substituting by boundary condition for $kT'_0(0)$ should it be $h_0[T_f-T_0(0)]$ or $h_0[T_f-T_0(0)]\over s$

Comment: The boundary condition is $KT'_0(0)=h_0[T_f-T_0(0)]$. The boundary conditions are in the $x$-domain !

Comment: I don't quite understand how you can first solve for $k{d^T_0(x)\over dx^2}-MT_0(x)=0$ and for that **simply just** add the constant $MT_a+Q_m$. What is the logic behind that. With the constant this looks like a non homogeneous equation right?

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify this detail.